# How to call IDL(Interactive Data Language) from java application?

Tags: java

I have designed a java application which opens a .dat file in ascii format.This .dat file calls a .pro file which I want to get executed in IDL. How can I do this?I have tried this much of code but it is not working.

```
public GLA14() //constructor
{
    super( );
    createAndShowGUI( );
    setVisible( true );
    setDefaultCloseOperation( WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );

    con=new java_IDL_connect();
    con.createObject();
    IDLConnectionReader outputListener=new IDLConnectionReader();
    con.addIDLOutputListener(this);
}

    private void setDefaultCloseOperation(int disposeOnClose) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

    private void setVisible(boolean b) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

    public void IDLoutput( JIDLObjectI obj, String sMessage ) 
{

        output.append( sMessage );
}
```